# Extending `find_by` with custom keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In ActiveRecord sometimes you have virtual attributes based on real attributes. I.E.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].reject(&:blank?).join ' '
  end

  def full_name= new_val
    self.last_name, self.first_name = *new_val.reverse.split(' ', 2).each(&:reverse!)
  end
end
```

Now lets say I want to support searching by full name. I can do something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.find_by_full_name name
    where("first_name || ' ' || last_name = ?", name).first
  end
end
```

This works but the search method is using the older `find_by_*` style finder rather than the newer `find_by attribute: value` style. Is there a hook where I can extend the newer style rather than have to use the old style?

I.E. I want:

```
User.find_by full_name: 'John Doe'
```

Rather than:

```
User.find_by_full_name 'John Doe'
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything else besides overriding the [`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by) method in `User` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   def self.find_by(*args)
     if args.first.key?(:full_name)
       where("first_name || ' ' || last_name = ?", args.first[:full_name]).where(args.first.except(:full_name)).take
     else
       super(*args)
     end
   end
 end
```

Give it a shot, seems to work fine on my side.